# Emulating sun reflection on fake ocean

Tags: light, lighting, distort

I have a sphere with emission material which supposed to be a sun. I have a glossy plane which supposed to fake relatively still water surface. [image: Scene]

I try achieve this effect. Long reflection on the water.
[image]
 I tried to use actual sun lamp but I didn't get this effect.
I achieve kinda this effect in another scene with ocean modifier and sun lamp but ocean modifier is heave on a system. [image] I there any way to make this reflection with glossy plane. Maybe some distortion or another glass plane?

P.S. Result with Rich Sedman's shader.
[image]
With increased roughness. 
[image]

Comment: You should add a Glare Filter in Compositor to achieve the sunset brightness in your example photo.  You can also *combine* noise textures to achieve finer "waves" on the surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a material similar to the following :

[image]

Here the 'sun' is an emissive sphere and a Bump node has been used on the plane to give the appearance of waves (from a Noise texture), using Fresnel to blend between Diffuse and Glossy. Be sure to keep a bit of Roughness to the Glossy shader (that's what causes the reflection to 'bleed' towards the viewer) and adjust the Diffuse shader to give a hint of color.

Comment: I applied this shader but result kinda scant. Reflection stretches along water surface for some distance but doesn't cover all of the length of the surface like on your screenshot. It differs on scale of noise texture but within some limits. I'll add result screen to my question.

Comment: Wow. The thing with roughness actually works! :)

Comment: From your screenshot it's hard to tell where the camera is located - try moving it closer to the plane. Imagine being stood on a beach - your eyes are only around 2m above the surface of the plane yet you can see 1000 metres - it's the glancing angle the helps.

Comment: Tried different angles but it changes a little. Roughness is the main ingredient I would say :)